# Deleting a Item from List View - Parse (Android)

Tags: java, android, listview, parse-platform

Hey guys im having an issue with deleting a object from a list view everytime the "Delete" button is pressed. For now ive replaced the code thats meant to be the delete function with a simple toast message just to let me know that the button works,  however nothing seems to appear on the screen so i assume that it is not working. When i click the delete button no error shows up on the log cat either.

I have followed a parse tutorial by android begin to create this simple list view but want to add more functionality.

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        // Pass the results into an ArrayAdapter
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(SelectCourse.this,
                R.layout.listview_item, R.id.text);
        // Retrieve object "name" from Parse.com database
        for (ParseObject course : ob) {
            adapter.add((String) course.get("name"));
        }
        // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        // Close the progress dialog
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        // Capture button clicks on ListView items
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    final int position, long id) {
                // Send single item click data to SingleItemView Class
                Intent i = new Intent(SelectCourse.this,
                        SingleItemView.class);
                // Pass data "name" followed by the position
                i.putExtra("name", ob.get(position).getString("name")
                        .toString());

                // Open SingleItemView.java Activity
                startActivity(i);

                //locate delete button
                deleteBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.delete);

                //create on click listener for the delete button
                deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        View parentRow = (View) v.getParent();
                        ListView listView1 = (ListView) parentRow.getParent();
                        final int position = listView1.getPositionForView(parentRow);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successfully Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                });
            }



        });
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it'd be better if you don't add the button `onclicklistener` in the `itemOnClickListener` of the `listview`.

Rather, override `getView` method of the adapter and there you should be using the following to set `onclicklistener` on the button like the following

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(SelectCourse.this,
                R.layout.listview_item, R.id.text) {

@Override

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

deleteBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.delete);

// add your button onclicklistener here
return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

}

};
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i just tried the code above and it still doesnt seem to be working :(. Do you think it is worth me putting the xml layout file in my question as well just so you could see how ive id stuff?

Comment: im not sure what you mean, sorry my android programming knowledge is very small.

Comment: ive tried editing the code to what you have suggested but its coming up with these errors :http://gyazo.com/89fd0f2c2e0187a903fae75d68abff52